# Can't kill subprocess after waiting

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, subprocess

I have a process running in a new Ubuntu shell, and I need to stop it after a certain period of time. My code looks like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args=['gnome-terminal', '--command=%s' % cmd])
print(process.pid)
time.sleep(5)
process.kill()
```

This should, I would have thought, start the process (in another shell), wait 5 seconds, and then kill it. However, when I run this code, it waits 5 seconds and then does nothing. Note that if I remove the `time.sleep(5)` line, `process.kill()` seems to work, killing the process instantly.

EDIT: I think I know what's going on. `process.kill()` doesn't kill the new shell, it's just that calling it immediately after creating the subprocess prevents the new shell from being opened in the first place.

In that case, how can I create a subprocess in a new shell that I can then kill at any point?

Comment: IIRC (I haven't used it in a long time…), the `gnome-terminal` program isn't the actual terminal program, it's a launcher that tells the existing terminal program to open a new window or tab (starting one if necessary), and then exits. In which case, killing that launcher doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want the command to run in a _terminal_ visible to the user?  That’s a lot more than a shell.